# Higher Chow group of complex field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, chow-groups

It is well-known fact that there is an isomorphism
$$
K_i(\mathbb{C})\simeq \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} &　\text{if } i:odd \\
0 & \text{if }i:even
\end{array}
\right.
$$
My question is that is there the following isomorphism?
$$
\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \textbf{CH}_n(\text{Spec}~\mathbb{C},i)\overset{?}{\simeq} \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} &　\text{if }i:odd \\
0 & \text{if } i:even
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: Your description of $K_*(\mathbb{C})$ seems not quite right: for example, $K_0(\mathbb{C})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, and $K_1(\mathbb{C})$ agrees with the unit group of $\mathbb{C}$, which is uncountable, hence cannot be $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. I believe I recall correctly that Suslin rigidity tells us that the profinite completion of $K_*(\mathbb{C})$ agrees with the profinite completion of what you wrote. But as far as I'm aware, it's still an open problem to give a simple, well-structured description of the higher $K$-groups of $\mathbb{C}$ before profinite completion.

Comment: To be careful about what kind of profinite completion I referred to: it is really that one must profinitely complete the space (or spectrum) $K(\mathbb{C})$, then take homotopy groups. This is of course not quite the same operation as simply profinitely completing the $K$-groups $K_*(\mathbb{C})$ themselves.